# How number of tasks will get execute if file have 4 partitions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a 560 Mb csv file, i have read the csv from HDFS. When i checked the number of partitions of the file using `df.rdd.partitions.size` it shows 4 partitions. If i just checked the total rows count using `df.count()` an job is submitted with 2 stages and 5 tasks for all stages.

I need to understand how the total number of stage is 2 and total number of tasks for all the stages is 5. I have learnt that 1 task for each partition so it should be 4.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8):

This is because `count` requires additional Stage. The first Stage reads your input file with 4 partitions (= 4 tasks), and each partition makes local row count. The second Stage has just one task which reads all previous counts (4 files) and sums them. So the entire **Job** has two Stages with 5 tasks total.